# Proof for dirichlet division approximation

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to find a proof for Dirichlet's division approximation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N d(n) = N \log N + O(N)$$
(where $d(n)$ is the number of numbers that divide $n$).

Is there any easy proof for it?  All I can find are quite hard proofs that don't actually prove everything but rely on other things.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at the proof of Theorem 3.1 here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/circledivisorsurvey.pdf). Its pretty elementary so if you still find it difficult then perhaps you need to brush up bit on the fundamentals.